# How to pass data to livewire component from javascript of the parent?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I know how to pass data from a parent component to a livewire component, but how to do it, if the value is dynamic and generated by JavaScript?

```php
<x-my-layout>
   <livewire:my-component id="test" foo="this value should be passed" />

   @push('scripts')
      <script>
         const livewireComponent = document.getElementById('test'); // <-- this is not working
         livewireComponent.setAttribute('foo', 'bar'); // <-- In consequence this is not working
      </script>
   @endpush
</x-my-layout>
```

Please don't answer, that I just can use `<livewire:my-component foo="bar" />`, because I need to pass a value that is generated on client side like an text input.

Comment: You can't do it like that. You would have to emit it as an event.

Comment: That's working. If you would add it as an answer, I could approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade-components are rendered server-side, and thus you cannot set that property via Javascript like that. You would have to emit an event instead. Here are some examples on how you can do that. All of these following examples that are event-based, which means that you would have to listen for it within your component by adding

```php
protected $listeners = ['setFooProperty'];

public function setFooProperty($value) 
{
    $this->foo = $value;
}
```

1. Using Alpine.js with `x-init`

```html
<x-my-layout>
    <div x-data x-init="Livewire.emit('setFooProperty', 'bar')">
        <livewire:my-component id="test" foo="this value should be passed" />
    </div>
</x-my-layout>
```

2. Using a global emit event with JavaScript

```html
<x-my-layout>
    <div x-data x-init="$wire.emit('setFooProperty', 'bar')">
        <livewire:my-component id="test" foo="this value should be passed" />
    </div>

    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            Livewire.emit('setFooProperty', 'bar'); 
            // or 
            Livewire.emitTo('my-component', 'setFooProperty', 'bar'); 
        </script>
    @endpush
</x-my-layout>
```